# Linearize a simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

This is homework. I have

$\displaystyle \qquad S\frac{dh(t)}{dt} + \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{h(t)} = q(t)$

and need to linearize it.

Setting all derivatives to zero, I get the steady-staty value of $h - h_0 = q_0^2R^2$.

Then, using Taylor series up to derivative one, only for the non-linear entity, I get:

$\displaystyle \qquad \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{h(t)} = \frac{1}{R}q_0R + \frac{1}{2q_0R^2}(h(t)-h_0) + error$

However, the stated solution for the non-linear entity (how is an element of a polynomial, that is between two pluses, called?) is:

$\displaystyle \qquad \frac{h(t)}{2R^2q_0}$.

So I have the numerator wrong. This looks so simple, that I can't imagine where it went wrong. Please advise!

Comment: What is $S$, a constant? Where did it go in what you did?

Comment: @Amzoti Indeed a constant. Later in the answer I review only the non-linear part of the equation.

Comment: If $q$ depends on $t$, how is $q^2R^2$ "steady state value"? Also, where did $R$ come from?

Comment: @PostNoBills, corrected. This describes the level of water in a tank with input q.`q0` is some constant inflow.

Comment: I still don't understand where $R$ came from. There is no $R$ in the equation, but there is $R$ in its solution.

Comment: Corrected again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linearized equation you obtained can be simplified to 
$$
S\,h'(t)-\frac{q_0}{2} + \frac{h(t)}{2q_0 R^2} = q(t)
$$
(I used the fact that $h_0=q_0^2R^2$.) The term with $h(t)$ is the same as in the book answer.